# Stop WebPage-Processing

Tags: asp.net

I have built an asp.net page that returns an image with `Response.BinaryWrite()`. This works fine but I have the following quesion.

I call `Response.BinaryWrite()` in the Page_PreLoad-event. I expect, that asp.net continues with the "normal" execution of the page till to `Unload` event, doing a lot of stuff that is no more necessary because all desired operation is already done. Am I right, and if yes, is there a possibility to tell asp.net that further processing is no more necessary for the page.

**Update:**

Thanks for all the answers. As suggested, I have used an ASHX-Handler, it was excactly what I needed. Thanks to all and +1 for all answers of this direction. For all who have the same question as I, the link from David Stratton shows a very simple way of how to do it.

Comment: Wow, we were all quick to come up with the httphandler idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Application.CompleteRequest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx) would do that for you.

> Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.

It can be accessed from a `Page` class this way:

```
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

However, if you want to only return an image, you should be creating a HTTP handler (class that implements [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx)) and not be using a `Page`. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx) MSDN article about creating HTTP handlers.

Comment: I dont't can find Response.CompleteRequest and I don't know how to access the HttpApplication-instance, the linked msdn-description mentions (sorry the question, I very seldom work with asp.net). Can you direct me how to access?

Answer (score 2):

You are right. But you should not be using a `Page` to return an image. Use an [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

use [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) instead of page

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `Response.End()`.
However, since you aren't using the ASPX featureset, you should move your code to an ASHX handler, which doesn't do any of the things you're trying to avoid in the first place.
You then wouldn't need `Response.End`, and you'd get better performance too.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but you can change the page to be an [ashx http handler](http://dotnetperls.com/ashx) to get rid of the overhead of the page lifecycle if that's what you're really trying to do.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link, helped my very fast. I have accepted oded's answer however, because he also answered the initial post. But I have used your ashx-solution. Thanks a lot.